# spark-submit, YARN with "cluster" deploy mode not working

Tags: spring, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to submit spark streaming app where the master is YARN and deploy mode is cluster. 
The initial error message is not being able to create JavaSparkContext:

> WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sparkGracefullTerminator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ssc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'streamingContext' defined in pokerStreaming.conf.MainConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext]: Factory method 'streamingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

Then I saw another error regarding connection to the driver:

> ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at XX.XXX.X.X:54035, retrying ...

So I guess the actual issue is with the connection to the driver.

Not sure how to further investigate it.
If the process is running on google Dataproc, doesn't the nodes suppose to have connectivity to each other?

Thanks,
Nir

Comment: Can you check if yarn Resource manager url is correctly specified in hadoop-env.sh ot hadoop-conf.xml file

Comment: Should I look for yarn.resourcemanager.address?
according to this:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

it supposed to be in yarn-default.xml, but i didn't find it there.
I did find yarn.resourcemanager.hostname under yarn-site.xml (and the address is based on the hostname according to hadoop link above).